# Need to export UPN's from a MSO Tenant

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm trying to export Group UPN's from a MSO Tenant. I can export individual groups but I need this to hit 6000+ groups.  Can any one out there help me figure this out?  Obviously I'm no expert with Powershell.  Who knows, I may not even be asking the correct question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Definitely not the right question for this platform. We can help you with issues faced in your code. What have you tried and what happened? Please update your question with the code you’re having trouble with and any errors received.

Comment: Heres the cmdlet I'm running.  All it does is give me an output file with 6500 blank lines:  Get-MsolGroup -ALL | Select-Object UserPrincipalName | Export-CSV C:\Temp\AllUPN.CSV -NoTypeInformation

Comment: The problem I'm running into may be that groups might not have UPN's but ObjectIDs

Comment: I was able to get GroupIDs from Azure.